# typeormconfig in root causes incompatiblity with npm run start:prod script

Tags: config, nestjs, typeorm

I have my `ormconfig.ts` in my project root, my nest app lives in an src folder which seems to be the default after generating a project with the nest cli. However when compiling my dist folder contains my src folder and  thus the default `npm run start:prod` command won't work since it refers to the `dist/main` folder, not `dist/src/main`. Now I can fix this in multiple ways but I was wondering if anyone faced this issue before.

dist:

```
ormconfig.ts
- src
-- modules
-- scripts
-- app.module.ts
-- main.ts
```

default start:prod command as generated by nest cli:
`node dist/main`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the `ormconfig` be a `ts` file in the project root, typescript will move js files to `dist` keeping the same directory structure that you already have. This means that the `src` directory will be kept because there's a ts file in the root. You can update the `start:prod` command to point to `dist/src/main` or you can make `ormconfig` not be a `ts` file

Comment: This was one of the things that I had come up with myself as well. For now its fine like that. The reason for keeping the config as ts atm is that I'm using a snakecase package in there.